# Getting uncaught error altough I'm using the exception in the constructor

Tags: php, exception, constructor, typeerror, strict

**I also included the following**

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
```

**Brief code testing strict types**

```
Class UsingStrict {

    private $name;

    function __construct(string $name) {

        try {
            $this->name = $name;
        } catch (TypeError $e) {
            echo "Caught the exception";
        }
    }
}

$variable = new UsingStrict(0);
```

**Gotten**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to UsingStrict::__construct() must be of the type string, int given
```

**Expected**

```
Caught the exception
```

I'm new to this, is it not possible to catch exceptions inside the constructor?

Comment: It's not getting that far. Since you're specifying `string` in the function itself, it will check it before it gets to the inside of the __construct() function.

Comment: @aynber That explains why it works upon wrapping the variable in try / catch, thank you, what's the correct approach to what I'm trying to accomplish? (excuse my broken English)

Comment: Why do you want to catch the exceptions?

Comment: You can 1) Check for the type before you pass it into the class, 2) wrap the class instance in try/catch blocks, and/or 3) remove the type-hinting from `__construct()` and instead do the checks inside the function.